# a NSManagedObject inherited class doesn't respond to addition

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a NSManagedObject model name A for which I create an addition A+Additions
But when I call a method from A+Additions the app crashes with unknown selector sent to object of class NSManagedObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found out that if you don't create the A.m from the editor menu,  the object in the xdatamodeld is not updated with the class name 'A' and defaults to 'NSManagedObject'.
So you have to manually set it and everythings works again.